# ValueError: time data 'Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, valueerror, strptime

I got a strainge bug.

Got 2 the same servers. Both ubuntu 22.04
both running Python 3.10.6

First server I run my code all well:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_time_str = 'Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET'
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
>>> print ("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))
The type of the date is now <class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
The date is 2023-02-28 11:27:38
>>>
```

Second server I do the same:

```
Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_time_str = 'Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET'
>>> date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z'
>>>
```

What could be causing this issue? its cleary not down to the format as its correct.

Comment: I get this error too, and it's because CET is not a recognised time zone name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Python strptime/strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) is a bit secretive about `%Z`: It does **not** parse arbitrary time zone abbreviations<sup>1</sup>. If you scroll down to the [technical detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) section, you can find:

> 6. [...] 
>    `%Z` [...]
>    strptime() only accepts certain values for `%Z`:
>
>    - any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale
>    - the hard-coded values UTC and GMT

The first point explains why your attempt works on *some* systems but not on others.

---

***How to parse reliably***

"CET" is an [abbreviated tz name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). Many of those are ambiguous, so parsers likely refuse to parse them<sup>2</sup>. A way around is to define which abbreviation maps to which [IANA time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) with [dateutils parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil # pip install python-dateutil

tzmapping = {"CET": dateutil.tz.gettz("Europe/Berlin")}

print(dateutil.parser.parse('Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET', tzinfos=tzmapping))

2023-02-28 11:27:38+01:00
```

---

If you want to have more control over the parsing process, you can implement something similar yourself, e.g.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+ standard library

tzmapping = {"CET": ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")}

date_time_str = 'Tue 28 Feb 2023 11:27:38 AM CET'

# separate datetime part and timezone part:
dt, tz = date_time_str.rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)

# now parse datetime part and set timezone.
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p').replace(tzinfo=tzmapping[tz])

print(date_time_obj)
# 2023-02-28 11:27:38+01:00

print(repr(date_time_obj))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 28, 11, 27, 38, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Berlin'))
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, `%Z` doesn't *parse* anything in a strict sense; it just makes the parser *ignore* strings like "GMT" or "UTC". The resulting datetime object will still be naive!

<sup>2</sup> Besides, CET specifies a UTC offset, not a time zone in a geographical sense. For instance "Europe/Berlin" and "Europe/Paris" both experience CET but are different time zones.

Comment: Thanks for clearify this. still strange that one system accepts its and an other system does not.

Comment: @user2433624 it *might* work if the tz abbreviation matches the time zone that the machine is configured to use. I don't think you can rely on this, so I wouldn't recommend to do so. See also my first footnote; it's kind of a shot to the foot anyway...

Comment: @user2433624 I've added a quote from the docs that might explain what you're experiencing - I'd still suggest to not rely on `%Z` if you can ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@FObersteiner your remark with matches the time zone on the machine seems to be the reason.

server that has the ValueError.

```
server2:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2023-02-28 15:06:10 UTC
           Universal time: Tue 2023-02-28 15:06:10 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2023-02-28 15:06:10
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

The server without the ValueError:

```
server1:~$ timedatectl
               Local time: Tue 2023-02-28 16:05:07 CET
           Universal time: Tue 2023-02-28 15:05:07 UTC
                 RTC time: Tue 2023-02-28 15:05:07
                Time zone: Europe/Amsterdam (CET, +0100)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
```

Since the code that was causing the issue is not mine change the system time zone made the application run without errors.

Comment: Python code should not require you to change the system timezone :)