# Can datetime convert the string '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern' correctly?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

This illustrates the problem:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

date_string = '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern'
date_format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format).astimezone(pytz.utc)
print(datetime_object)
```

Error:

```
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
```

The time zone "US/Eastern" is not treated correctly. What is the solution?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) - _"`strptime()` only accepts certain values for `%Z`: 1. any value in `time.tzname` for your machine’s locale; 2. the hard-coded values `UTC` and `GMT`"_

Comment: Try using other python libraries like delorean, maya, moment, arrow, or datautil.

Answer (score 1):

`strptime`'s %Z does not parse time zone names, although that might be a useful feature. [See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75591607/10197418). However, you can split date/time and timezone part in the string and treat them separately. You don't need any third-party libraries for this. EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo # Python 3.9+ standard library

date_time_str = '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern'

# separate datetime part and timezone part:
dt, tz = date_time_str.rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)

# now parse datetime part and set timezone.
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tz))

# with pytz, use localize!
# pytz.timezone(tz).localize(datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'))

print(date_time_obj)
# 2023-03-03 15:40:00-05:00

print(repr(date_time_obj))
# datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 3, 15, 40, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delorean library:

```
import delorean

date_string = '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern'
last_space_index = date_string.rfind(' ')
dt_c = date_string[:last_space_index]
tz_c = date_string[last_space_index + 1:]
dt_object = delorean.parse(dt_c, timezone=tz_c).datetime
print(dt_object)
```

This will separate the timezone and datetime from the string and parse the date and time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution in the previous answer. I believe this function does that.

```
def  parse_time_zone(date_time_str):
  # separate datetime part and timezone part:
  dt, tz = date_time_str.rsplit(" ", maxsplit=1)
  # now parse datetime part and set timezone.
  return datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo(tz))
```

In addition, I also found a solution converting another pandas function.

```
def test_parse_time_zone():
   import pandas as pd
   date_string = '20230303 15:40:00 US/Eastern'
   df = pd.DataFrame({'date_string': [date_string]})
   # Convert the 'date_string' column to a datetime object
   df['datetime_object'] = df['date_string'].apply(parse_time_zone)
   # Convert the datetime object to a string
   df['new_date_string'] = df['datetime_object'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
   print(df)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).